# Is there a way to make a python program un-closable?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've seen many programs unable to close on windows. When you go to the task manager they say something like "Operation is not valid for this process."

On windows, is it possible to make a python program not able to shut down via the red 'x' or task manager?

Comment: Disabling the close button in the title bar (and the corresponding menu item in the system menu) is trivial. After all, the application is only asked to exit. Disabling process termination, however, is not possible in general. (A virus would love such a feature!)

Comment: [The arms race between programs and users](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040216-00/?p=40603).

Answer (score -1):

to make it unclosable via the red "x" this is the code i dont know how to make it unclosable via task manager
but anyways here's the code:

root.overrideredirect(True)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).